# Exact filter when multiple values/html elements in a cell

Tags: yadcf

This might be more DataTables related than specifically YADCF but I'm asking it here as an obvious enhancement if the feature doesn't exist.

I have a column/s which can contain multiple value 'tags', similar to the YADCF examples. The filters to allow filtering by these tags generate correctly.

JSFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/wallacio/622704ep/6/

See columns titled **Area** and **Rig** (excuse the horrific colours...!)

If I wish to see only the events in **South**, I need to use `filter_match_mode: "exact"` (to exclude those in South West, South East etc)

There is an event (8th down in unfiltered view) which contains tags "South" and "South East" 
[Event containing South and South East tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8SHh.png)

When the filtering for "South", this event does not appear, presumably because the exact filter is matching against the contents of the cell as a whole and not against each discrete HTML element within it.

I could change filter_match_mode to "contains" but this would result in events which are tagged "South East" etc appearing, which is undesirable.

I've had a trawl through the source and can see that this is taken into account when generating the filter options, but apparently not when filtering, which is why I wonder if it's a limitation caused by how DataTables filters are implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `filter_type: 'custom_func',` and write your own filtering logic for that specific column

```
column_number: 0,
filter_type: 'custom_func',
custom_func: myCustomFilterFunction,
data: ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

where `myCustomFilterFunction` looks something like

```
function myCustomFilterFunction(filterVal, columnVal) {
        var found = false;
        if (columnVal === '') {
            return true;
        }
        switch (filterVal) {
        case 'one':
            found = //some logic goes here
            break;
        case 'two':
            found = //some logic goes here
            break;
        case 'three':
            found = //some logic goes here
            break;
        default:
            found = false;
            break;
        }

        if (found) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```